# React Native Sentry Source maps not working

Tags: react-native, source-maps, sentry

I have tried to get source maps working with react native and sentry but I keep getting this type of output with no meaningful line numbers:

```
i@file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/G4535-H056800I/AppName.app/main.jsbundle:
[Filtered]@file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/G4535-H056800I/AppName.app/main.jsbundle:
[Filtered]@file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/G4535-H056800I/AppName.app/main.jsbundle:59:1255
[native code]
```

I did the following to create and upload the source maps for my release:

**1. Create map/bundle artifacts**

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8081/index.ios.map -o index.ios.map  
curl http://127.0.0.1:8081/index.ios.bundle -o index.ios.bundle
```

**2. Edit last link in index.ios.bundle to point to map**

```
WAS: `//# sourceMappingURL=/index.ios.map`
NOW: `//# sourceMappingURL=index.ios.map`
```

**3. Create Release on Sentry**

```
curl https://app.getsentry.com/api/0/projects/appname/releases/ -u "username": -X POST -d '{"version": "version_num"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

**4. POST artifacts to Sentry release**

```
curl https://app.getsentry.com/api/0/projects/appname/releases/version_num/files/ -u "username": -X POST -F file=@index.ios.bundle
curl https://app.getsentry.com/api/0/projects/appname/releases/version_num/files/ -u "username": -X POST -F file=@index.ios.map
```

Have I missed something? Been playing around with this for some time and can't get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: can you file a ticket with support@getsentry.com? we'd be happy to help.

Comment: Brien, did you ever get this working?

Comment: @bgmaster No I'm afraid I didn't. I got some help from sentry but still had the same issue. That was a couple of years ago. Things might have improved since then